# Block in block doesn’t execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have ViewController with -updateUI method. It is needs to be called periodically while AVPlayer plays.

So this is in -viewDidLoad (note, self.track is not a AVPlayer instance, it is instance of class Track with almost the same method that AVPlayer has):

```
__weak ViewController * selfWeak = self;
[self.track addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 20)
                                         queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                                    usingBlock:^{
                                        [selfWeak updateUI];
                                        NSLog(@"THIS BLOCK DOESN'T EXECUTE");
}];
```

This is implementation of this method in Track Class:

```
- (void) addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:(CMTime)interval
                                      queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
                                 usingBlock:(void (^)(void))block
{
        self.periodicObserverBlock = block;
        self.observeQueue = queue;
        self.observeInterval = interval;
        self.waitingToObserve = YES;
}
```

Property declaration:

```
typedef void(^observeHandler)();
@property (nonatomic, strong) observeHandler periodicObserverBlock;
@property (nonatomic) CMTime observeInterval;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t observeQueue;
```

I’m saving it for time, when AVPlayer ready. When it is ready, I’m doing this:

```
- (void) afterLoadingMethod
{
        __weak Track *selfWeak = self;
        [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:self.observeInterval
                                                  queue:self.observeQueue
                                             usingBlock:^(CMTime t){
                                                 (void) selfWeak.periodicObserverBlock;
                                                 NSLog(@“THIS BLOCK EXECUTES”);
                                             }];
}
```

The problem is that block that says -updateUI doesn’t execute. (It is marked with NSLog(@“THIS BLOCK DOESN’T EXECUTE)). Block that calling in Track class executes. So I think problem is somewhere in storing properties, somewhere here

```
self.periodicObserverBlock = block;
```

Or here:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) observeHandler periodicObserverBlock;
```

But I didn’t figured it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Timothy nailed it. BTW, if `selfWeak` or `periodicObserverBlock` could _ever_ be `nil`, you should check to make sure for this before calling this block, because unlike sending a message to an object, invoking a `nil` block will crash your app. Also, make sure you handle the race conditions correctly. Also, Apple advises that block properties be defined as `copy`, not `strong`.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Didn’t know about copy. Will getter always return a copy of block in that case? And how can `selfWeak` be nil? It was just assigned from `self`. If `self` is `nil`, that method will never been executed.

Comment: Re `copy`, the [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW12) says: "Note: You should specify `copy` as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen automatically, but it’s best practice for the property attribute to show the resultant behavior."

Comment: Re `selfWeak`, the scenarios to be worried about is the race condition whereby the block starts or was dispatched to one queue, and the object is deallocated on another. Perhaps your code is written to mitigate against this, but as a matter of practice, `weak` memory semantics means "the object can be deallocated and this pointer can be set to `nil`", so you should guard yourself against that scenario. Whenever you write code with `weak` variables, you should make sure you handle `nil` scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Things getting extremely complicated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just referencing the block:

```
(void) selfWeak.periodicObserverBlock;
```

To call the block, use parenthesis:

```
selfWeak.periodicObserverBlock();
```